# I am not able to get False boolean value from user input

Tags: python, while-loop, boolean, user-input

```
s  = True
while s == True:
   #taking input from the user
   num1 = int(input("enter a number: "))
   sign = input("enter a sign from :+ , - , * , /")
   num2 = int(input("enter a second number: "))
   #calculation
   if sign == "+" :
      print(f'the sum of {num1} and {num2} is {num1+num2}')
   elif sign == "-" :
      print(f'the difference of {num1} and {num2} is {num1-num2}')
   elif sign == "*" :
      print(f'the multiplication of {num1} and {num2} is {num1*num2}')
   elif sign == "/" :
      print(f'the difference of {num1} and {num2} is {num1/num2}')
   else:
      print('invalid sign')
   s = bool(input("type True to start the calculater and False to stop the calculater: "))
```

whatever the user input is, it is converted to True
how can I convert the input to False so that I can get out of the loop

Comment: When calling `bool` with a string parameter only an empty string will give you `False`. See [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth) in the documentation.

Comment: You are confusing `bool` with `eval`. `bool` just determines if its argument has a truthy value; it does not parse the string to see if it is a particular Python Boolean literal.

Comment: But don't use `eval`: just compare your input to the string `"True"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother with Boolean literals. Just do explicit string comparisons. Also, use the infinite-loop/explicit-break pattern rather than a Boolean flag.

```
while True:
    ...
    s = input("type True...")
    if s != "True":
        break
```

You can replace `s != "True"` with any more involved check that ignores case distinctions; allows synonyms for "True" or "False" like "yes"/"no", "T"/"F", etc; or other checks.

---

The root of your problem is that `bool` does not parse a `str` value looking for a `bool` literal. Empty strings are `False`; all other strings are `True`:

```
>>> bool("")
False
>>> bool("True")
True
>>> bool("False")
True
>>> bool("not True")
True
```